# Braintree-Web ApplePaySession constructor is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, braintree, applepay, applepayjs

I am trying to implement Apple Pay on checkout in a react project using Typescript. I have installed the braintree-web package and followed the instructions on braintree's website to initialize my `ApplePaySession`. Although typescript allows me to compile the project, in the browser my call to `new ApplePaySession(3, paymentRequest);` is undefined. I have wracked my brain, but I cannot understand what is going wrong. Here's a code snippet for how I have initialized ApplePay.

```
import { applePay, ApplePayStatusCodes, ApplePaySession } from 'braintree-web';

...

beginApplePay() {
    if (!this.btApplePayInstance) {
      //throw an erro
    }

    const paymentRequest = this.createPaymentRequest();
    const session = this.createSession(paymentRequest);

    session && session.begin();
  }

  createSession(
    paymentRequest: braintree.ApplePayPaymentRequest
  ): braintree.ApplePaySession | null {
    let session: braintree.ApplePaySession;
    console.log('creating session');
    console.log('Sample payment request: ', paymentRequest);
    console.log(
      'Supports API v3: ' + window.ApplePaySession.supportsVersion(3)
    );


    try {
      debugger;
      session = new ApplePaySession(3, paymentRequest); //this is where it fails
      console.log(session);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      //throw an error
      return null;
    }
```

This is what my browser says: 
`TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new braintree_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ApplePaySession"](3, paymentRequest)')`

Any insight into what's going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I figured out that this is a typescript specific problem. In the type definitions for braintree-web, they define a type of `ApplePaySession`. When the project is built, the browser thinks that `ApplePaySession` is a reference to some class in the braintree-web when in fact it is a reference to the `ApplePaySession` native to the safari browser.

The solution I found was to use the types for ApplePayWebJS and reference the `ApplePaySession` provided there. However, this did produce some problems further down the line when trying to get the types of the two packages to play nicely together.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.55.0/js/apple-pay.min.js"></script>
```

at the top level Js file worked for me then just using @ts-ignore when using the session.

Ugly work around I know... If you have found a better solution please share.